# Filtering in a query for onPremisesImmutableId no longer works after upgrading to Microsoft Graph .NET SDK v5

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Before the upgrade, we used the `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`. I replaced it according to these [upgrade instructions](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication).

```
private static GraphServiceClient CreateClient()
{
    var accessTokenProvider = new BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider(new TokenProvider());

    return new GraphServiceClient(accessTokenProvider);
}

private class TokenProvider : IAccessTokenProvider
{
    public async Task<string> GetAuthorizationTokenAsync(Uri uri, Dictionary<string, object> additionalAuthenticationContext = default,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        AuthenticationResult token = await Global.Msal.AcquireTokenAsync(Global.MsalScopes.MicrosoftGraph);

        return token.AccessToken;
    }

    public AllowedHostsValidator AllowedHostsValidator { get; }
}
```

I migrated the query as follows, also according to the [instructions](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#authentication):

```
var client = Global.MicrosoftGraph.Client;
string base64Guid = Convert.ToBase64String(guid.ToByteArray());

var result = await client.Users.GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"onPremisesImmutableId eq '{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64Guid)}'";
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id" };
});
```

If I use the filter parameter `onPremisesImmutableId` replace with surname the query works.

If I use the v4 again with the `DelegateAuthenticationProvider`, the code works as well.

Comment: Does it return any exception or what's the actual result?

Comment: There is no error message. The result.Value is just null. When I filter by Surname, a Microsoft.Graph.Models.User object comes back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new SDK v5 does the `UrlEncode` automatically. As soon as you remove the manual encoding from version v4, the code works.